# Is this the proper way to overload[] with a composed vector class

Tags: c++

I am building a custom vector class with an `std::vector` as its sole member, and adding a variety of math functions to it by overloading +,- and others.

I am doing this for direct accessing vector elements:

```
template <typename T, int N>
class Vector{

    std::vector<T> v;

public:

    Vector():v(N,0){}

    const T& operator[](int i)const{
        return v.at(i);
    }
    T& operator[](int i){
        return v.at(i);
    }
```

Is this an acceptable technique for overloading in this case, such that I can read an element from a `const Vector<...>` as well as assign to an element from a non-const? Since `at` returns a reference, one could assign to an element correctly in this case?

Comment: It's ok, except `int` instead `size_t`

Comment: @Lol4t0 Actually it should be [`std::vector<T>::size_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at).

Comment: Are you aware of [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray)?

Comment: @Angew I had not hear of that before, fascinating I'm taking a closer look now, thanks.

Comment: @Angew after doing considerable reading around, the consensus is that `valarray` is not worth using and that it is no more efficient than `vector` and in fact its implementation has not been updated in many years and many compilers don't support its suggested optimizations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's a perfectly reasonable use of overloading. I question the use of `at`, however. It would be better to have both `at` and `operator[]`, which pass through to their `std::vector` counterparts. This way, you give the caller the choice between safety and performance (which is why the two versions exist in the first place).

Comment: And doing what people will expect.

Comment: I took your advice and also changed the function parameter from `int i` to `typename std::vector<T>::size_type i` -- good idea?

Comment: @Fellowshee: Yes, but you'll find things are a bit cleaner if you add `typedef typename std::vector<T>::size_type size_type;` as a public member declaration. Then you can refer to just `size_type` everywhere else.